# How to get multiple values from a form and separate them with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, eloquent, slim

I don't know how this type of form done. I am not sure if this approach is correct.

I created a form which creates a delivery from a list of products. these products have an id (product_id) and quantity in the SQL table.

[image]

HTML code

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity[]"  value="{{ product.product_id }}">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity" value="0" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control form-control-sm">
```

I need to get quantity value for that particular product. I figured out until here but I don't know how to separate quantity array with PHP to be able to make it like a string so I can update the product quantities in the database.

Quantity output with below inputs:

[image]

```
$quantity = $request->getParam('quantity');
var_dump($quantity);
die();
```

[image]

I am using slim framework 3 and eloquent

Comment: serialize everything and then you can manuplate the string with regex. i am not sure what string you will get in your form but this is how you can do it

Comment: Please show us the output/dump of the `quantity` array.

Comment: @waterloomatt I just updated my question with the output. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *product_id* as the key for the quantity array which will give you a nicely formatted array to work with.

```
<input type="text" name="quantity[{{ product.product_id }}]" id="quantity" value="0">
```

This should give you:

```
array (size=1)
  'quantity' => 
    array (size=2)
      'ABC' => string '0' (length=1)
      'DEF' => string '0' (length=1)
```

With that, you can:

```
foreach ($request->getParam('quantity') as $productId => $quantity) {
    // Create/update query.
}
```

Comment: sorry what about doing this instead of having a extra hidden input                                                                 <input type="text" name="quantity[{{ product.product_id }}]" id="quantity" value="0" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control form-control-sm">

Comment: Yip - you could remove the hidden input. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

to make a string from the array you can use `implode()` its default function of php

for example:

```
$arr = array('1','2','3','4');
$arr_string = implode(" ",$arr);
echo $arr_string;
```

it will return you string something like `1,2,3,4`